# Create Entity Model of Data in Azure Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure, webforms

I have created an ASP.NET Azure WebForms application. It has its default database and I can access it & modify AspNetUsers table using IdentityModel.cs (EntityFramework) as shown in many sites.

Now I have created other tables in the database namely "Projects", "customers", etc. and also have designed aspx forms based on those fields. Now I am not able to get, how to associate these forms wit the tables in the database. I wouldn't prefer Scafolding as many sites show, instead I would prefer something like IdentityModel does. I can have control to retrieve data, display, show, edit, add functions based on my button clicks or so.

I read many tutorials & blogs but couldn't get how to achieve this as I want. Tutorials shows using Scaffolding & MVC. I also looked to add "Entity Data Model" in projects, but none create .cs file; so again lost their. Can anyone please help me know how can I achieve what I am trying to.

Please any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you are looking for is the ability to reverse engineer a model from existing tables.  This is possible, although can be a little painful if your existing database has a complex schema.  If you are using Studio 2013 you can add a New Item of type `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` and on the screen that appears choose `Code First from Database`.  You need to then point the wizard your db connection string.  This will create the context classes, entity classes and configuration that you need.

More details are in [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx) from Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks AlexC. It helped me get a way.